# React Native Request failed with status code 400

Tags: react-native, axios

Does anyone have experience working with this API:
https://authenticjobs.com/api/docs#introduction

I have been running through a few iterations of implementation in my React Native project and I was originally getting this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.longitude')

And now I am getting this error:

> Request failed with status code 400

This is the action creator that is attempting to log the `data` object of this API request.

```
import axios from "axios";
import reverseGeoCode from "latlng-to-zip";
import qs from "qs";

import { FETCH_JOBS } from "./types";

const JOB_ROOT_URL = "https://authenticjobs.com/api/?";
const JOB_QUERY_PARAMS = {
  api_key: "5634cc46389d0d872723b8c46fba672c",
  format: "json"
  // latlong: 1,
  // radius: 10,
  // q: "javascript"
};

const buildJobsUrl = zip => {
  const query = qs.stringify({ ...JOB_QUERY_PARAMS, l: zip });
  return `${JOB_ROOT_URL}${query}`;
};

export const fetchJobs = region => async dispatch => {
  try {
    let zip = await reverseGeoCode(region);
    const url = buildJobsUrl(zip);
    let { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: data });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: 400 status comes when the data you post is courrpt or not valid..

Comment: @MurtazaHussain, I didn't `post()` any data though. I was trying to fetch data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this refactor, although this is going to kind of take my application in a different direction:

```
import axios from "axios";

import { FETCH_JOBS } from "./types";

const JOB_ROOT_URL = "https://authenticjobs.com/api/?api_key=";
const JOB_QUERY_PARAMS = {
  key: "a446a0eefe6f5699283g34f4d5b51fa0",
  method: "aj.jobs.getLocations",
  format: "json",
  category: "javascript"
};

export const fetchJobs = region => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const url =
      JOB_ROOT_URL +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.key +
      "&method=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.method +
      "&category=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.category +
      "&format=" +
      JOB_QUERY_PARAMS.format;
    let { data } = await axios.get(url);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS, payload: data });
    console.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```